# javascript function to redirect any time a specific url is reached?

Tags: javascript, function, redirect

I'm a student learning JavaScript.  I don't know how to do this, but I imagine there has to be a way to.

I'm looking to reference a script throughout my website so that any time a specific URL is reached (which can be accessed through most pages within the site) the script redirects the page to a different URL just after the original URL is loaded.

I'm imagining something like this,though I know this doesn't work:

```
function urlRedirect (onload = "window.location.href= 'url1.com'")
{
   window.location.replace = 'url2.com'
};
```

I'd also be interested if this possible outside of JavaScript if anyone can think of how to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: `if (a == 'something') { doB() }`

Comment: meta refresh, php redirects, htaccess rewrite/redirect, etc

Comment: you could just replace the links on page load with a different href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assign the function to the window *onLoad* event.

```
window.onload = function(){
  if (window.location.href == 'http://url1.com'){
    window.location.replace('http://url2.com');
  }
}
```

Haven't tested the code but something like that should work.

Comment: The answer posted by Bun also works and you could assign that function to the _onLoad_ event as well.

`window.onLoad = urlRedirect();`

or

`<body onload='urlRedirect()'>`

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you read basic [JavaScript Syntax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_syntax.htm) first.

I guess that the function you want:

```
function urlRedirect() {
  if (window.location.href == 'url1.com') {
    window.location = 'www.url2.com';
  }
}
```